# Can you do an IF conditional from a JSON payload that looks for a specific value in the key value pair?

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, transactional-messaging-api

I've got a JSON payload that has an itemStatus in there.  The itemStatus is either "Cancelled", "Backordered", or "".  I need to strikethrough in CSSthe Item Name if the status is Cancelled.

I would have thought I could do something like this, but it's not working.  Am I formatting incorrectly?

`{{#if (itemStatus == "Cancelled")}}text-decoration: line-through;{{.else}}{{/if}}">{{ItemName}}`

Comment: Please update your question to include a sample of the JSON and more of the relevant code for your send context.  What you've provided is hardly enough to provide substantive assistance.